# Using Firebase like Socket.io?

Tags: firebase

I want to create a mobile (NativeScript) and desktop app (Electron.js) that can trigger events that can be caught and handled by the server and then emit events to all clients, or at times just some of them, so that clients can display messages based on the kind of event triggered by the server.

I created a prototype Electron app using socket.io and it works well, however I want to use Firebase. Can Firebase do the same? It seems that FCM may work, but it is not entirely clear to me based on their documentation.

If FCM doesn’t work, what would be the best way Firebase could emit events to clients and also respond to events emitted by them?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use Cloud functions which are being triggered by any changes in the Firestore, but if this is not what you want Callable functions and HTTP triggered functions also can be used as a way to trigger after the desired event on any of the clients and pass it to the FCM.